# Remapping the keyboard under Windows 8.1

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping

I wish to remap an unused key into a key combination. I am a handicapped user and not of the related questions seem to answer my needs.

My handicap requires me to enlarge the displayed portion of my Chrome browser. Generally speaking control+ serves my purposes well but is becoming more and more difficult for me. I wish to take some unused key(such as ) and remap that into the desired keyboard combination.

Any idea how I can best accomplish this?

Thanks.

Ross

Answer (score 2):

There is perhaps a way to do this within Chrome; but I would suggest investigating [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), as you may have similar requirements for remapping keys to combinations in other applications.

The following script should remap the `Pause` (`Break`) button to `Ctrl +` (zoom in) when the Chrome window is active:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ahk_class Chrome_WindowImpl_0 

Pause::
    Send, ^{+}
```

*(save as, for example, `chrome.ahk` and double-click to run)*

If you use `Chromium`, you can change the first line to `#IfWinActive ahk_class ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1`.

I will leave it to you to determine other hotkeys (such as zooming out). I have no affiliation with AutoHotkey, but it may be valuable for you if you envision wanting to remap keys to suit your accessibility needs elsewhere. As it happens, I will be leaving this script in-place for myself as I find myself zooming in frequently in Chromium due to my own poor eyesight.

Comment: That works wonderfully!  Even better it is fully integrated with the On-screen Keyboard!

Comment: Glad to hear it @greenber :) AHK is pretty powerful, so hopefully it will fit some needs that you haven't even discovered yet!

Comment: You know what they say about having a hammer, right? Once you have one, everything starts looking like a nail.